# R not reading the header (not able to use filter/select/any pipe operator)

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I am learning R and facing some issues.

I imported the data, and I am able to produce a summary and sum specific column like (df1$yield_ha). But when I am trying to filter yield_ha I error: object yield_ha not found. I do not understand what exactly the problem is with the code or if R is not reading the header

my code:

```
df <- fread(paste(DIR,"test.csv",sep="/"), data.table = F)
summary(df)
head(df, n=10)

df1 <- df
view(df1)

sum(df1$yield_ha)

df1 %%
  filter(yield_ha > 200) #error: Error in filter(yield_ha > 200) : object 'yield_ha' not found
```

I need to use the filter, and select functions/pipe operator. But none of them are working and I am getting an error that object not found

Comment: The pipe operator is `%>%`, not `%%` (that's modulo).

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your pipe operator. The pipe operator `%>%` from `magrittr` or `|>` from base R passes the object as the first argument of the right-hand size function.

`%%` is the modulus operator, therefore, `df1 %% filter(yield_ha > 200)` is trying to access the `yield_ha` object from the global environment, which does not exist.